# On Click Button To check all the checkbox

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check all the checkboxes and changing the name of the button.But the checkboxes are not checked.  Here is the code i am trying to implement.

```
function js_select_all(btn){
    var tf = "on";

    if (btn.value == "Check All") {
        for (var i=0 ; i < document.formMassCheckIn.circSelected.length ; i++) {
            alert("check1");
            if(!(document.formMassCheckIn.circSelected[i].checked)) {
                alert("check2");
                document.formMassCheckIn.circSelected.checked = tf;
            }
        }
        btn.value ="Uncheck All";
    } else {
        for (var i=0 ; i < document.formMassCheckIn.circSelected.length ; i++) {
            alert("check3");
            if (!(document.formMassCheckIn.circSelected[i].checked)){
                alert("check4");
                document.formMassCheckIn.circSelected.checked = "";
            }
        }
        btn.value = "Check All";
        tf = "";
    } 
}
```

Comment: i think you missed index number while checking checkbox, instead of `document.formMassCheckIn.circSelected.checked = tf;` try `document.formMassCheckIn.circSelected.checked[i] = tf;`

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
document.formMassCheckIn.circSelected[i].checked = true;
```

for checking the checkbox

and

```
document.formMassCheckIn.circSelected[i].checked = false;
```

for unchecking it

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily, check the code below

```js
var button = document.querySelector('.btn');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Button Value
  (button.value == "check All") ? button.value = "uncheck All": button.value = "check All";

  // Checkbox
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
  [].forEach.call(checkboxes, (checkbox) => {
    if (checkbox.checked)
      checkbox.removeAttribute('checked');
    else
      checkbox.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">

<input type="button" class="btn" value="check All">
```

Answer (score 1):

You've missed the index `[i]` and also you should use `true/false` to `check/uncheck` the checkboxes :

```
document.formMassCheckIn.circSelected[i].checked = true;
//And
document.formMassCheckIn.circSelected[i].checked = false;
```

Also you shouldn't add the Logical NOT `!` operator in the second condition for the `Uncheck All` should be :

```
if (document.formMassCheckIn.circSelected[i].checked)
```

Instead of :

```
if (!(document.formMassCheckIn.circSelected[i].checked)){
```

Or it will be never reached.

Hope this helps.

```js
function js_select_all(btn){
  if (btn.value == "Check All") 
  {
    for (var i=0 ; i < document.formMassCheckIn.circSelected.length ; i++) {
      if(!document.formMassCheckIn.circSelected[i].checked)
        document.formMassCheckIn.circSelected[i].checked = true;
      
    }
    btn.value ="Uncheck All";
  } else 
  {
    for (var i=0 ; i < document.formMassCheckIn.circSelected.length ; i++) {
      if (document.formMassCheckIn.circSelected[i].checked)
        document.formMassCheckIn.circSelected[i].checked = false;
    }
    btn.value = "Check All";
  } 
}
```

```html
<form name='formMassCheckIn'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='circSelected' /> Option 1
  <br>
  <input type='checkbox' name='circSelected' /> Option 2
  <br>
  <input type='checkbox' name='circSelected' /> Option 3
  <br><br> 
  <input type='button' value='Check All' onclick='js_select_all(this)'/> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the earlier posts already covered the answer.

I would like to point out that your question itself contains the answer.

```
if(!(document.formMassCheckIn.circSelected[i].checked))
```

You are checking for boolean in the above if statement. But inside the if block, you are setting string to the *checked* property of check box.

Answer (score 0):

You made a few mistakes in your function. Except everything good. I have rewritten your function to do same thing as you did and also cut offed some unwanted code.

```
function js_select_all(btn) {
    if (btn.value == "Check All") {
       for (var i = 0 ; i < document.formMassCheckIn.circSelected.length ; i++) {
           document.formMassCheckIn.circSelected[i].checked = true;
       }

       btn.value = "Uncheck All";
    } else {
        for (var i = 0 ; i < document.formMassCheckIn.circSelected.length ; i++) {
            document.formMassCheckIn.circSelected[i].checked = false;
        }

        btn.value = "Check All";
    } 
}
```